# identify which select has submitted the form

Tags: html, select

I have a HTML form, with three select options. and im submitting the form using 'this.form.submit()' for all the three selects. Is there a way to identify, which select triggered the submit?
Any sort of help would be deeply appreciated.

```
    <form action="mypage.php" method="post">
    <select name="mysel_1" id="mysel1" class="form-control" required 
    onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="1">val 1</option>
    <option value="2">val 2</option>
    <option value="3">val 3</option>
    <select>
    <select name="mysel_2" id="mysel2" class="form-control" required onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="1">val a</option>
    <option value="2">val b</option>
    <option value="3">val c</option>
    <select>
    <select name="mysel_2" id="mysel2" class="form-control" required onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="1">val x</option>
    <option value="2">val y</option>
    <option value="3">val z</option>
    <select>

    </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

First assign values to each option using :

```
<option value = "somevalue"> option 1 </option>
```

Then print out the value to see which one was submitted.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There are three selects and they can have same values for the options. So, we can't rely on that

Comment: If you could post the part of the code you are working on it might help define a solution.